# XCode Library not found for -lssl

Tags: xcode

I keep running into a problem where if I have XCode running for a little while, it starts throwing build errors when I try to run the simulator that say "Error: Library not found for -lssl"

[image: Error: Library not found for -lssl]

I can make it stop by quitting XCode, and reloading the project, but it happens again after a little while.

I don't know if I can add the library somewhere, but also I don't know why it works at first, but not after a while.